# how to display error details in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Sample console output from nodejs, I could access,

```
error.code

error.errno

error.sqlState

error.index
```

but how to access this string where it says "`Column 'name' cannot be null`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a printable message, you can use

```
error.toString();
```

Or to get the actual message,

```
error.message;
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: I realize the problem is with `JSON.stringify(error)`, as this is what I'm sending back to the client, and client never gets the string representation

Answer (score 0):

`error.message` would do the trick

If your `error.message = "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'name'` cannot be null" and you are only interested in **"Column 'name' cannot be null"** you can create your own custom error class (for this particular sql errors) and make it return the later part of colon only. The logic would be somet hink like

```
if(error.sqlState !== undefined){
  // only do it for sql error
  throw new CustomSqlError(error);
}
```

and something like

```
function CustomSqlError(err){
  if(err && (err.sqlState!== undefined)){
    this.err = err;
  }
}

util.inherits(CustomSqlError, Error); // needs require("util");

CustomSqlError.prototype.getMsgWithutSQlCode = function(){
  if(typeof this.message == "string"){
    return (this.message.split(":"))[1].trim();
  }
}
```